# Conflict between \captionof and mdframed

Tags: listings, captions, mdframed, minted, framed

I'm using the `minted` package to generate highlighted code snippets. Because I want all `minted` environments to be wrapped with `mdframed`, I added the following to the preamble.

```
\usepackage{mdframed}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{mdframed}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{mdframed}}
```

I also want to caption the listings. Since I have listings that are more than one page long, I don't make them into a float; instead, I add a caption and a label with `\captionof{listing}{...}\label{...}` *after* the `\end{minted}` closure. The problem is that when I do that, the `mdframed` environment doesn't spread nicely across pages as it usually does. Instead, I get the whole listing crammed (truncated, actually) into a single page.

I've identified that either the `caption` package or the `\captionof` command are the culprit.

Do you know any solutions?

**Edit**: I've identified the source of the problem more precisely: it's the `\captionof` command from the *previous* `minted` environment that messes up the *next* one. If I just add a caption to the last one, for example, it doesn't happen.

**Edit**: I got it to work if I put the caption *below*, but if I put it above the listing it still messes up.

---

Without `\captionof`:

[image: no caption]

---

With `\captionof`:

[image: with caption]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched in the `caption` package documentation, and found that the `captionof` command needs to be inside an environment for it to work. Adding enclosing braces (`{}`) around the listing, including the `captionof` command, seems to fix the problem.

Comment: \captionof permanently sets \@captype, which the extra group (breaces) will correct.  Without a readable copy of your code (no screenshots) there isn't much else to say.